# Creating a HeatMap from a Pandas MultiIndex Series

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I have a Pandas DF and I need to create a Heatmap. My data looks like this and I'd like to put the Years in Columns, the Days in rows and then use that with Seaborn to create a heatmap

I tried multiple ways but I was always getting "inconsistent shape" when I chose the DF, so any recommendation on how to transform it?

Year and Days are the index of this series

2016

```
  Tuesday  4
  Wednesady 6
  .....
```

2017

```
  Tuesday  4.4
  Monday   3.5
 ....
```

import seaborn as sns
ax = sns.heatmap(dayofweek)

Comment: It would help if you could create a minimal code example that reproduces your error.    This will make it a lot easier to help others figure out what is going on and help.

Comment: thanks, it's true.. I was wondering how as my code is based on an extract of another database and in one of the transformations I ended up with that summary table. But the basic question is: If I have a multi index series, with Level0=Years and level1=Months for example and I want to have the Years in columns and then create a heat map like a matrix with Months in Rows and Years in Columns and the data inside.. how can I move the data from one format to the other?

Comment: In my experience, taking the time to create a minimal example can often help you solve your own problem.  A "toy example" allows you to more easily experiment and distill the question down, as well as clarifying for others what exactly you are looking for.  This process definitely takes more time, and it can be annoying to try to pull out a small piece of code from within a larger and more complicated routine, but it is worthwhile.  Here are the [stack overflow guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on creating such an example!

Comment: thanks, and yes... I'll certainly take into account.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have a DataFrame like this:

```
years = range(2016,2019)
months = range(1,6)

df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([years,months]))
df['vals'] = np.random.random(size=len(df))
```

You can reformat the data to a rectangular shape using:

```
df2 = df.reset_index().pivot(columns='level_0',index='level_1',values='vals')

sns.heatmap(df2)
```

[image]

Comment: I think you got exactly my question and your last part of transforming the levels 0 and level1 into rows and columns is exactly what I wanted.

Nevertheless my table that looks very much like the one you simulated rejects that transformation with this message 

Traceback (most recent call last):

KeyError: 'level_1'

Comment: If I type 
dayofweek.index
I guet
MultiIndex(levels=[[2016, 2017, 2018, 2019], ['Friday', 'Monday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday', 'Thursday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]],
           names=['YR', 'DOW'])

Comment: Since your indexes have names, they are preserved when doing `reset_index()`, the `pivot` must then use the correct column names: `df.reset_index.pivot(columns='YR', index='DOW', values='<name of the column containing the values>')`

Comment: If you consider your question answered, consider accepting the answer by clicking on the check mark on the left to close the topic